# Remove Duplicate Messages from Maildir

Tags: maildir

I've got a bunch of duplicate messages in my IMAP server's Maildir. What's the best way to remove them?

Some relevant points:

- Shared Message-ID is usually a good enough definition of duplicate. A tiny script that removes all but one of the duplicate messages would work.
- Sometimes it's necessary to find duplicates based on shared message bodies. What's a reasonable definition of shared here? Bitwise equivalent? What about weird differences in line wrapping, escaping, character encoding?
- Sometimes there's some meaningful difference between 'duplicate' messages. What's the best way to review the differences in sets of 'duplicate' messages? Diffs?

Answer (score 10):

I've made some significant improvements to Kevin's script mentioned above, and he was kind enough to accept my pull requests.  Eventually we split this off into a dedicated project which you can find here:

https://github.com/kdeldycke/maildir-deduplicate

Comment: This script [moved to a new location](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2013/06/maildir-deduplicate-moved/) so I updated the link.

Comment: AFAIU you always can install it by `pip install mail-deduplicate`.

Answer (score 3):

for generic files in linux, I use fdupes utils to remove duplicate files. I found it also works for Maildir messages.

Comment: [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) seems to work for exact duplicates only, while the OP is (implicitly) asking about more complex patterns of duplication.  A message delivered twice because of `.forward` or whatever will have slightly different headers, so while the message itself is a duplicate, the two files containing the two copies may not be.

Answer (score 1):

Best I've found today is Kevin Deldycke's [maildir-deduplicate](https://github.com/kdeldycke/maildir-deduplicate).

- It ignores the `X-MIMETrack` header by default and compares headers using the `SHA224` digest.
- It automatically deletes duplicates without asking for confirmation; however there is a dry-run mode which allows previewing which duplicates will be deleted.

I bet someone could make something fancy from Rick Sanders' [delIMAPdups.pl](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/files/delIMAPdups.pl), part of his [IMAP Tools](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/).

Comment: `maildir-deduplicate` [moved to a new location](http://kevin.deldycke.com/2013/06/maildir-deduplicate-moved/) so I updated the link.  However your information is now out of date.

Comment: I've updated this so that there is no longer misleading outdated info.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Dovecot for IMAP access, you can use the following command:

```
doveadm deduplicate -u user@yourdomain.com mailbox INBOX
```

to remove duplicates from your INBOX folder.

As Dustwolf commented, if you want to match emails in all folders, type the following instead:

```
doveadm deduplicate -u user@yourdomain.com ALL
```

It should take care of everything, all duplicate emails should be deleted right away.

If you have very specific needs like filter on size or only for new messages, I suggest that you look into the [Dovecot Search Query documentation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/SearchQuery) as well as the [doveadm deduplicate documentation](https://wiki.dovecot.org/Tools/Doveadm/Deduplicate) and adapt the command to your needs.

Comment: This only takes care of the INBOX folder, to match everything, use `ALL` instead of `mailbox INBOX`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome's Evolution [a graphical mail user agent] has a built-in  feature to remove duplicate mail. As explained on this [help page](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-duplicates.html), it boils down to:

1. Select the suspect messages (or just all messages)
2. Go to menu *Messages*, the choose *Remove Duplicate Messages*.

Voilà.

P.S. Evolution can access your messages locally (MailDir, MH, Mbox) or over IMAP.